# Reconstruction of commutative differential graded algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, higher-category-theory, derived-categories, differential-graded-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

Let $A,B$ be commutative differential graded algebras (cdga) over $k$ such that $H^{i}(A)=H^{i}(B) =0 \ (i>0)$.

Here, differentials are defined cohomologically, i.e,
$$
\cdots \rightarrow A^{i-1} \overset{d_A}{\rightarrow} A^i \overset{d_A}{\rightarrow} A^{i+1} \overset{}{\rightarrow} \cdots
$$
where $d_A$ is the differential of $A$.
In other word, $A,B$ are connective.

We also denote the dg categories of dg $A$-modules and dg $B$-modules by $D_{dg}(A),D_{dg}(B)$, respectively.

**Question**
If $D_{dg}(A),D_{dg}(B)$ are quasi-equivalent as dg categories, then $A, B$ are quasi-isomorphic as cdgas ?

**Edit(10/4,5)**
Also, are there any candidate of conditions for cdgas for the reconstruction theorem(including the version below) to hold?
Or is it solved under some assumptions?

Any comments and references are welcome. Thank you !

Please take a look at the useful comments.

The same question is in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4771259/952389).

**Edit (a variant of the question, 9/20)**:

Let $\tilde{D}_{dg}(A),\tilde{D}_{dg}(B)$ be dg-derived categories, i.e, $\tilde{D}_{dg}(A) = D_{dg}(A)/ Ac(A), \tilde{D}_{dg}(B) = D_{dg}(B)/ Ac(B)$,
where $Ac(A) \subset  D_{dg}(A), Ac(B) \subset D_{dg}(B)$ are the full sub dg categories of acyclic complexes of $D_{dg}(A),  D_{dg}(B)$, respectively.

If $\exists F: \tilde{D}_{dg}(A) \rightarrow \tilde{D}_{dg}(B)$ are quasi-equivalent of dg categories and $H^0(F)$ is a monoidal functor between monoidal categories $H^0(\tilde{D}_{dg}(A)), H^0(\tilde{D}_{dg}(B))$, then $A,B$ are quasi-isomorphic ?

**Edit (classical case, 9/21)**:

When we consider two commutative rings $A,B$, where we regard them as cdgas in degree $0$.
Even in this case, is the question true ?

**Edit (10/4)**
Can my series of questions be solved from Toen's dg Morita theory or Lurie's theory of higher algebra?
Or is this exactly what should be studied in the future?

Comment: I believe the key phrase here is "(derived) Morita theory." There is a wide literature on this, for example, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408337), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3673), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310146), or [here](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s2-39.3.436), to start. It may also help to reference [Cohn](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2587) or [Cisinski and Tabuada](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3717) for a quick overview of model structures on DG categories, as well as other work of Tabuada on those model structures.

Comment: Putting together results from these references, I think that if $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent $k$-algebras, viewed as DG-$k$ algebras in degree $0,$ they should have quasi-equivalent DG-derived categories, but not necessarily be quasi-isomorphic as DG-$k$-algebras.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the many references!
I understand the classical (derived) Morita theory. I want to know whether generalized results are well-known or not.

Comment: There is also a difference between dgas and cdgas. The dg-category $D_{dg}(A)$ depends only on $A$ as a dga/$E_1$-algebra, and there can be several non-equivalent $E_\infty$-algebra structures on such $A$. So the answer to the question is "no" for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Do you have any literature that elaborates on what you mentioned? In addition, can we expect to improve the situation by making any assumptions about $A$?

Comment: @MarcHoyois "and there can be several non-equivalent $E_\infty$-algebra structures on such $A$" --- this is actually false, when one works over a field of characteristic zero. This is Theorem A of https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03585
.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! So is it still possible that the question I am considering is correct?

Comment: @Stahl: the OP assumes commutativity, and ordinary commutative $k$-algebras are Morita equivalent iff they're isomorphic (because the module category knows the center of a ring). So this approach won't work for producing a counterexample.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, you're right -- I see now that I missed the (c) assumption in the OP

Comment: @DanPetersen Oh this is a surprise, thanks for the reference!

Comment: You might find https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/tilting7.pdf interesting, especially Section 5

Comment: In the case where $A,B$ are in degree $0$, this is true, because you can then recover $A$ as $\pi_0$ of the derived center of this category. Other than that, I don't know - I want to point out that there are other settings where this is false. As Marc points out, away from char 0, you can at best require $A,B$ to be quasi-iso as $E_1$-rings, and this becomes a reasonable question (although in char $0$ they are equivalent) - if you work $K(n)$- or $T(n)$-locally everywhere, there are counterexamples to even this version.

Comment: Thank you. What is the definition of derived centers?

Comment: In $\infty$-categorical terms, it's simply the endomorphism ring of the identity functor of a given (say, stable) $\infty$-category. In dg-terms, it's something like Hochschild cohomology

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Are there some good references to what you said?

Comment: Certainly yes - I'm not super familiar with dg literature but this cannot not be in there somewhere; in $\infty$-categorical language, the definition and description of the center is done in Higher Algebra (under the name "$E_1$-center"), and the description of its $\pi_0$ in the case where $A$ is discrete follows from the earlier comparison of the homotopy groups of mapping spectra with Ext-groups. (but this approach really only works when $A$ and $B$ are in degree $0$)

Comment: Thank you! Is Lurie's Higher algebra the best reference for E1-center? Are there any other good references?